# RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'request_UserID'. Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, tedious

Tyring to connect and Select record from MSSQL using NodeJS and tedious

Here is my code

```
connection.on("connect", function (err) {

    sqlCommand = new Request(
        "SELECT * FROM video.videoView WHERE Id = @Id AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), request_userID) = @request_UserID",
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    );
    sqlCommand.addParameter("Id", TYPES.UniqueIdentifier, data.vid);

    sqlCommand.addParameter(
        "request_UserID",
        TYPES.VARCHAR,
        data.email_address
    );

    sqlCommand.on("row", function (columns) {
        columns.forEach(function (column) {
        });
    });

    sqlCommand.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(sqlCommand);
});
```

Here is the error message

**RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'request_UserID'. Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined**

I looked into this example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15

In the example they do not query using parameters. I need to use parameters to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Have you tried `TYPES.VarChar` instead of `TYPES.VARCHAR` yet?

Comment: Thanks you so much @AlwaysLearning it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change TYPES.VARCHAR to TYPES.VarChar

Thanks @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Pay it forward
Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here. [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)